# Highlight ping if the user is in the chatroom, Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want it to highlight a ping (@test) only if the user is in the chatroom. If not, don't highlight. Right now I have:

```
function highlight(message){
    return message.replace(/@\b([A-Za-z0-9]+)\b/g, '<span class="name-color">@$1</span>');
};
```

[Project Source Code](https://repl.it/@Froggers/Froggy-Chatroom#index.js) - line 150

Comment: You'll need to write code to do that; what have you tried?

Comment: is this on a client-side, in the browser? do i understand correctly that for each user, you want to only highlight chat messages which contain their username?

Comment: if you want to get an answer, please put the relevant parts of the code in your question, give a bit more details about what you're doing and describe what you've tried. it's unlikely someone will want to make an effort to go to the external link and look through over 150 lines of code, so you should show some effort first.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What you can do, is keep a list of usernames on the clients and server (give to new clients connecting), and then check if that username is in that list, if so then highlight the ping.

The code I got was:

```js
function highlight(message){
    if(message == "") {
        return message
    }
    let mentions = message.match(/@\b([A-Za-z0-9]+)\b/g)
    if (mentions === null) { return message }
    for (i = 0; i < mentions.length; i++) {
        let mention = mentions[i].substring(1)
        if(sesskx.has(mention)) {
            message = message.replace(mentions[i], `<span class="name-color">@${mention}</span>`)
        }
    }
    return message
 };
```

## Explaination:

1. It takes the message, and finds all mentions
2. it loops over all mentions
3. if the mention is in current users it highlights it

EDIT: repl link: https://repl.it/@Codemonkey51/Froggy-Chatroom

Comment: https://repl.it/@Froggers/Froggy-Chatroom#index.js it is line 150.

Comment: did you figure it out yet?

Comment: It's not working, it says: Cannot read property 'length' of null

Comment: Fixed (i think at least)

Comment: read my last comment, you almost got it, try to fix it.

Comment: Can you check it now (I added a catch case for no mentions)

Comment: Oops, I only changed the stack overflow answer, check my repl now

Comment: Are you sure? I can see the change, if you can't just add: if (mentions === null) { return message } before the for loop

Comment: Just looks like this:

  function highlight(message){
    if(message == "") {
        return message
    }
    let mentions = message.match(/@\b([A-Za-z0-9]+)\b/g)
    for (i = 0; i < mentions.length; i++) {
        let mention = mentions[i].substring(1)
        if(sesskx.has(mention)) {
            message = message.replace(mentions[i], `<span class="name-color">@${mention}</span>`)
        }
    }
    return message
 };

Comment: Sure, I'll send you edit access, but I'm like 99% sure I added it

Comment: my name is UnluckyFroggy on repl.it

Comment: Sent the invite now